# Android SDK Save line breaks from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, fileoutputstream

I've an multiple line EditText but when I try to save the text to a file, I can't see the line breaks when I open it.
My `EditText` `inputType` is `TextMultiLine`.

This is my code

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(cat + ".planit", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    EditText note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
    String content = data + "date=" + date + "&---&SPLIT&---&color=" + color
            + "&---&SPLIT&---&note=" + note.getText() + "&---&SPLIT&---&"
            + "PLANIT-STRINGSPLIT";
    fos.write(content.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    MainActivity.Error(AddTaskActivity.this);
} catch (IOException e) {
    MainActivity.Error(AddTaskActivity.this);
}
```

And to show it in TextView:

```
ScrollView sV = new ScrollView(this);
RelativeLayout rL = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout rLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.items);
TextView note = new TextView(this);
rL.addView(note);
sV.addView(rL);
rLay.addView(sV);
```

Comment: What are you opening the file in?

Comment: In a textview. Sorry, I forget to mention.

Comment: Please show that code - to open the file and display..